# Error when calculating prediction error for logistic regression model

Tags: r, logistic-regression, predict

I am getting the following error: **$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors**. I am getting the error when trying to calculate the prediction error for a logistic regression model.

Here is the code and data I am using:

```
install.packages("ElemStatLearn")
library(ElemStatLearn)
# training data
train = vowel.train
# only looking at the first two classes 
train.new = train[1:3]
# test data
test = vowel.test
test.new = test[1:3]

# performing the logistic regression
train.new$y <- as.factor(train.new$y)
mylogit <- glm(y ~ ., data = train.new, family = "binomial")
train.logit.values <- predict(mylogit, newdata=test.new, type = "response")
# this is where the error occurs (below)
train.logit.values$se.fit
```

I tried to make it of type list but that did not seem to work, I am wondering if there is a quick fix so that I can obtain either the prediction error or the misclassification rate.

Comment: in predict add `se=TRUE`

Comment: Awesome, thank you. So now I have the standard error. To get the misclassification rate how would I proceed?

Comment: search is your friend, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146294/what-is-misclassification-rate-how-do-we-calculate-it